# Eclipse: what's the good way of launching an application with arguments?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I've been using Eclipse for years, and I'm quite familiar with it, but this still bothers me, I want to know if I'm missing something.

Suppose I want to run my runnable `MyClass.java` from the IDE. The standard way is, with the source selected

- `Right Click -> Run-As -> Java Application`

or, equivalently through the `Menu -> Run -> Run-As -> Java Application`

Now, suppose I want to run it with some arguments, or some special setting (output redirection, alternate JRE, etc). In Eclipse, that's managed via Launch Configurations. In my case, I'd do `Right Click -> Run-As -> Run Configurations...` to access the stored Configurations, find the one (perhaps several) corresponding to `MyClass`, edit the settings and run it.

Now, here's my little problem. If I wanted to run `MyClass` with arguments straight away... it seems that I need to go through this two-step procedure: 1) run it for a first time without arguments so that Eclipse (under the hood, rather misteriously) creates a blank Launch Config, and 2) invoke `Run As...` so that the LaunchConfig editor is opened? It looks cumbersome and unnatural to me.
I'd wish to do "Run as Java, let me edit the configuration first".

Of course, I can go `Right Click -> Run-As -> Run Configurations...` and create manually the configuration, but this is not ideal : Eclipse does not autofill the Java source from which I triggered the creation, nor even can guess the application type (Java in this case), I must do this myself (that's why I resign to the 2-step procedure mentioned above, it's more direct).

Notice that this is not specific to running Java apps.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You may add variables to the Run config and prompt the user to enter the value when you run the application.

I have attached an example -

[image]

Next time when you run the application it will directly prompt you to enter the value.

Hope that helps !